what's the point of saying "a person skilled in the art will so and so" in the specs?
What's the point of saying "a person skilled in the art will so and so" in the specs?
I see this quite commonly. What does it achieve?

I am not a lawyer. I think using the phrase "a person skilled in the art will..." is used to avoid having to describe explicitly how commonly used technologies work which is tedious. There are also probably good legal reasons too, but I'll leave them up to the lawyers to describe.
